# Generate json object from variables and insert into another json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, database, data-structures

This question is purely syntax. I'm trying to insert a generated JSON object into another JSON object.

Let's say my JSON looks like this:

```
var database =
{
  "john": {
    "pwd": "somehashrighthere",
    "mail": "example@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

This object stores a hash and an email under the users name. Now I want to insert a new user:

```
var name = "somename";
var pwd = "hash";
var mail = "email@email.net";
```

If I try to insert this into a json object as by

```
database.name =
{
    "pwd": pwd,
    "mail": mail
}
```

I would expect an output that fills the gaps:

```
{
  "john": {
    "pwd": "r1pper",
    "mail": "example@gmail.com"
  },
  "somenamerighthere": {
    "pwd": "hash",
    "mail": "email@email.net"
  }
}
```

Instead the javascipt takes the expression quite literall:

```
{
  "john": {
    "pwd": "r1pper",
    "mail": "example@gmail.com"
  },
  "name": {
    "pwd": "pwd",
    "mail": "mail"
  }
}
```

I'm quite new to javascript/json and would appreciate if you guys exlain to me how one could dynamically(!) generate json objects and feed them into a bigger data structure. None of the answers I found on SO could solve this problem in a way I could understand. Do I need to make changes to the datastructure, or have I just misunderstood the javascript/node.js syntax. Thanks in advance :)

Edit: I solved the problem quite simply. Turns out javascript actually passes the variables into the json and I was just confused:

```
{
  "john": {
    "pwd": "r1pper",
    "mail": "example@gmail.com"
  },
  "name": {
    "pwd": "hash",
    "mail": "email@email.net"
  }
}
```

Now we just need to pass the name dynamically, which can be solved by treating the JSON, as if it was an array:

```
database[name]
```

treats `name` as a variable.

Edit 2:

The comments below came in while editing. I apologize for that.

Comment: `database[name]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `database[name]` (take the value of `name` and use as index)

instead of `database.name` (use the string `'name'` as index)